# calling associative arrays

Tags: bash, array, associative-array

Team, am setting some variables in an associative array but its output is not resulting anything.. any hint?>

```
#/bin/bash

#IOEngine="psync"
#TestType="read"
IOEngine="libaio"
TestType="randread"

vars_ioengine_defaults() {
declare -A associative_vars
  RunTime="0"
  UDCNAme="stage"
  if [[ "$IOEnginge" == "psync" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "read" ]]; then
    declare -A associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="0" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="3G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024" [DFLT_Threads]="1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="3M")
  elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "randread" ]]; then
    declare -A associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="0" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="1G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="8,16,32" [DFLT_Threads]="16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="32k")
  elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "libaio" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "read" ]]; then
    declare -A associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="16" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="3G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024" [DFLT_Threads]="1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="3M")
  elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "libaio" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "randread" ]]; then
    declare -A associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="16" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="1G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="8,16,32" [DFLT_Threads]="16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="32k")
  else
    echo " Neither IOEngine nor TestType variables matched to required  values"
  fi
}

vars_ioengine_defaults
echo fio_gen ${associative_vars[DFLT_QueueDepth]} ${associative_vars[DFLT_DatasetSize]}
```

output:

```
prints nothing: no output here <<
```

expected output:

```
fio_gen 16 1G
```

Comment: Is that the actual script you're running? How are you running it?

Comment: its already resolved below. not sure why closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is only visible in your function. It works if you define the variable in the main scope and assign the values in the function:

```
#/bin/bash

#IOEngine="psync"
#TestType="read"
IOEngine="libaio"
TestType="randread"

declare -A associative_vars

vars_ioengine_defaults() {
  RunTime="0"
  UDCNAme="stage"
  if [[ "$IOEnginge" == "psync" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "read" ]]; then
    associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="0" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="3G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024" [DFLT_Threads]="1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="3M")
  elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "randread" ]]; then
    associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="0" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="1G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="8,16,32" [DFLT_Threads]="16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="32k")
  elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "libaio" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "read" ]]; then
    associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="16" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="3G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024" [DFLT_Threads]="1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="3M")
  elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "libaio" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "randread" ]]; then
    associative_vars=([DFLT_QueueDepth]="16" [DFLT_DatasetSize]="1G" [DFLT_BlockSize]="8,16,32" [DFLT_Threads]="16,32,64,128,256" [DFLT_FileSize]="32k")
  else
    echo " Neither IOEngine nor TestType variables matched to required  values"
  fi
}

vars_ioengine_defaults
echo fio_gen ${associative_vars[DFLT_QueueDepth]} ${associative_vars[DFLT_DatasetSize]}
```

Comment: trying to figure out if there is any issue in your syntax in the IFs.. observe some $ with spaces. or are you still formatting your script? ex:  [DFLT_BlockSize]="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024" $ not sure if this $ is needed here

Comment: oh u meant to use ) instead of $?

Comment: Edited! No, just move `declare -A associative_vars` out of the function and remove the `declare -A` when you assign the values.